# Spring jms and ibm mq

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq

I want to send jms message over IBM MQ with my message id.
My code

```
public void sendAntiFraudRq(String msg, String corr) {
    LOGGER.info("Sending to AntiFraud = {} with correlationID = {}", msg, corr);
    jmsTemplate.send(AntiFraudRqQueue, session -> {
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
        message.setJMSCorrelationID(corr);
        message.setJMSMessageID(corr);
        return message;
    });
}
```

But IBM MQ gives my message such id

```
<MessageID>ID:000d51204d515f544553545f43524d5fa9f7e55903d0ed56</MessageID>
```

how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't set your own MessageId - bad idea and goes against IBM MQ Best Practices. Let MQ generate a unique MessageId for you.

Secondly, MQ expects both a MessageId and CorrelationId to be a byte[] and MQ will convert the byte array into displayable hexadecimal and then save it to the header.  So, what you are seeing is correct.